# Blocking IP addresses via iptables not taking effect

Tags: debian, iptables

I am trying to ban various IP subnets on my Debian server by using the following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 222.128.0.0/10 -j DROP
```

The command was taken correctly and a `iptables -L -n` command shows them as follows:

```
root@server:~# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  43.229.53.41         0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  222.128.0.0/10       0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  222.186.21.236       0.0.0.0/0
DROP       all  --  185.41.168.0/22      0.0.0.0/0
```

But when I use tcptrack to view open connections, connections are still open (over 900 of them!).

Do I need to 'reload' the settings but into iptables in any way? I do not really want to reboot the server

Output from `iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers`

```
root@server:~# iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 13283 packets, 9904K bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                         tion
1       18  1080 DROP       all  --  *      *       43.229.53.41         0.0.0.0                                         /0
2       28  2628 DROP       all  --  *      *       222.128.0.0/10       0.0.0.0                                         /0
3        0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       222.186.21.236       0.0.0.0                                         /0
4     5911  236K DROP       all  --  *      *       185.41.168.0/22      0.0.0.0                                         /0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                         tion

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 19416 packets, 11M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destina                                         tion
```

Comment: Could you replace that `iptables` output with the output from `iptables -L -n -v --line-numbers`?  Counts on those rules would be most interesting.

Comment: @MadHatter updated question with output from that command, thanks

Comment: How long since you put those rules in?

Comment: About 15 minutes ago

Comment: See womble's excellent explanation below (+1 from me!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DROP` rules are working, because there are packet counts against them.  I don't know exactly how `tcptrack` works, but it is likely that it is seeing open connections which were setup before you added the `DROP` rules, but will no longer pass traffic (because any incoming packets, be they data or acks, will fall on the floor).

Comment: Data, ACKs, or even RSTs!